# Check what view file ZF2 is trying to load?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am building my first ZF2 application, and in one of my modules, the views associated with my controller are not loading. Is there a way I can check what view path ZF is trying to execute?

I have checked all of the file paths and module config settings, and they seem correct, and all of my other modules that have the same layout work fine, so I am thinking this is either a filename or namespace issue.

Comment: Any error? If a view is not found, usually there is an exception thrown. And if there is some view grabed automatically, then you should see something pretty fast

Comment: I get no error, just a completely blank response. Just to be random, I created a module that had no associated view file, and that also gave the same output, a 0 byte empty document. No error showed up in my Zend Server log either.

Comment: Please make sure your Module is loaded and provide the following: route-config for the route you're accessing, view-config parts, controller of your view, please also make sure your Module.php loads the correct config file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [Zend-developer-tools](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendDeveloperTools) it shows you in the toolbar which layout, template is used.

To your problem - in module you can replace the template from other modules. But it should depend on template path stack.

In module.config.php, you should have something like:

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        'application' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
```